Why doesn't this xargs and mv command work?
I want to mv the latest file to the specified directory.
ls -1t ~/Downloads | head -1 | gsed 's|^|~/Downloads/|g' | xargs -I {} mv {} ~/test/

Output:
mv: rename ~/Downloads/latest.jpg to /Users/home/test: No such file or directory

But following command does work:
mv ~/Downloads/latest.jpg ~/test/

So I think the reason it doesn't work is the xargs command.
My environment is MacOS.

~ is only special to the shell itself when parsed as syntax. It's not special to mv or any other command, so when xargs adds it to an argument vector it isn't honored.

Looks too fragile to use ls ans pipes like this.

Well, yes; parsing the output of ls is a well-known antipattern. But I don't think that means you need to resort to perl.

On macos you should have zsh available, and then just cd ~/Downloads && mv *(.om[1]) ~/test/ should work instead of all this hassle...

Oh, and we even have an exact dupe for that.

@CharlesDuffy agreed, that's a better target for the immediate problem, my VTC was a bit off - "here's how you'd normally do that" shouldn't be a dupe target for "why doesn't my way work" questions.

The immediate problem is that ~ isn't expanded by either xargs or mv, so your command is looking for a filename with a literal ~ character in it.
The larger problem is that trying to parse output from ls is innately unreliable.
Using BashFAQ #99 practices to find the latest file without resorting to ls -t:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Underscore prefixes avoid restricting destination variable names
newest_file() {
  local _file
  local -n _dest_var=$1; shift
  _dest_var=$1; shift || return
  for _file; do
    [[ $_file -nt $_dest_var ]] && _dest_var=$_file
  done
}

newest_file newest ~/Downloads/*
mv -- "$newest" ~/test

This avoids the problem because the ~ characters -- used in an unquoted context in your source code -- are shell syntax rather than data; the shell replaces ~/test with /home/youruser/test before mv is started.
